# Adding a alert to a button click

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have been trying to add a alert to my button which updates a users details in a database.

I have tried adding a onclick method directly to the button and using functions but it doesn;t seem to work.

My button is;

```
<input type="submit" id="profileclick" value="Update" class="button-link"/>
```

And I am submitting the form by: (if it is important)

```
<form id="profile" method="post" action="../script/updateUserDetails.php">
```

One of the ways I tried was

```
$('#profileclick').click(function(){
 alert('Your details have been updated');
 $('#profile').submit();
});
```

In all instances the details update but I do not receive a alert.

Comment: `window.alert('your message');`

Comment: are you sure the JS is actually executing? getting the update just means the form was submitted via normal methods.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to work?"  That could mean any number of things.

Comment: You need to prevent the default action to begin with.

Comment: @ explosion pills .... It doesnt work.....I just want a pop up box to display the message but I recieve nothing.

Comment: @user1941674, please tell us you are including the jQuery library and you did use `$.ready` and enclosed your JS appropriately

Comment: Yes I did, this is only a snippet

Comment: I do know how to use it but this isn't working for some reason. I have done alot more complicated things than this. People on here can be very rude @Ghillied . I have just decided to use a simple `window.alert`.

Comment: @user1941674 : oddly your alert code works http://jsfiddle.net/fgE5n/ ;)

Comment: @user1941674 My comment was not said to be rude at all. It is better to master walking, before running... otherwise, one might faceplant. I am sorry you misunderstood my intentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#profileclick').click(function(){    
     alert('Your details have been updated');
     $('#profile').submit();
});


$('#profile').submit(function( e ){
         e.preventDefault();

         // ........ AJAX SUBMIT FORM
});
```

Or simply add a delay before you submit using `setTimeout` ...

```
$('#profileclick').click(function(){    
     alert('Your details have been updated');
     setTimeout(function(){
             $('#profile').submit();
     }, 2000);        
});
```

Comment: in that case the form will never be submitted ;)

Comment: @JFK sure it will, just use a bit of AJAX magic, otherwise you cannot expect anything from your page if it refreshes, right? what you think?

Comment: I might know that but if the OP copies your answer he might not get what he is expecting. In your sample I think binding a `click` event to the `submit` button is redundant when you could set the alert inside `submit()` method (after `preventDefault()`)

Comment: thanks roXon. Nice to have people who are constructive and not rude when responding to posts @Ghillied

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#profileclick').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the form from being submitted by the button
    // Do your thing
    $('#profile').submit(); // now manually submit form
});
```

EDIT:

Just a note. This won't prevent the form from being submitted by other means, such as pressing Enter inside a text field. To prevent the form from being submitted at all, you have to preventDefault() on the form itself, as given in the other answer.